# MvcFileUploader 1.3.2 not saving file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using MvcFileUploader 1.3.2 http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcFileUploader/ the demo does not save the uploaded file to the server for me.

I am using VS2010.

To replicate create a new web project and get the nuget package

```
PM> Install-Package MvcFileUploader
```

Run the project and navigate to the Demo

```
http://localhost/MvcUploaderTest/Demo
```

Upload a file using the controls, I'm using a small jpg.  You should see a JSON result returned. The first entry is the error and mine looks like this.

```
 {"files":[{"error":null,...
```

Check the upload directory and see if the file was uploaded or not.

```
~/Content/uploads/
```

No errors or exceptions from the application or in the logs.  Can anyone get this demo to work?

This looks like a useful package which uses a nice jquery file uploader.  It has an Html Helper for razor, creates thumbnails, and you can associate uploaded files to entities.  I have looked into using http://backload.org/ but it's much heavier and seems like a lot more configuration.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is the JSON returned

```
{
"files": [{
    "error": null,
    "name": "C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\txt.jpg",
    "size": 286054,
    "type": "image/bmp",
    "url": "/MvcUploaderTest/DownloadFile?fileUrl=/Content/uploads/C:\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Content\txt.jpg\u0026mimetype=image/bmp",
    "delete_url": "/MvcUploaderTest/DeleteFile?entityId=1234\u0026fileUrl=/Content/uploads/C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\txt.jpg",
    "thumbnail_url": "/Content/uploads/C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\txt.jpg?width=80\u0026height=80",
    "delete_type": "POST",
    "FullPath": "C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\uploads/C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\txt.jpg",
    "SavedFileName": "C:\\MvcApplication2\\MvcApplication2\\Content\\txt.jpg",
    "Title": "txt"
}]
```

}

Comment: Work as promised, I tried it just a minute ago. If the uploaded image is displayed in the upload dialog it was uploaded, it is liked to the uploaded file.

Comment: The uploaded image doesn't display for me.  The progress bar just keeps going.  @developer10214 Which version of VS and ASP.MVC are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 & VS 2012 and MVC4

Comment: Thanks.  Still doesn't work with no indication why.  I step through the code in MvcTestControllerDemo UploadFile and it appears to work but no file is saved.

Comment: The path is very weird. /Content/uploads/C:\\MvcApplication2\\

Comment: We're using the Backload component in our company. You do not need to configure anything. Just install the NuGet package and your done. Only if you need to set different storage folders, change the thumbnail size etc. you add a configuration setting for this special purpose. Look into example 1 on Github. There is no configuration at all.

Comment: I was using Backload at first and it works fine but wanted to try MvcFileUploader 1.3.2 because it had a nice HtmlHelper and just seemed lighter for what I needed. I agree Backload works great and has everything you need I just wanted to try and get by with the cleaner HtmlHelper with the other package.  Since I can't get it to work I might just go back to using Backload.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using IE8

The problem is Request.Files[0].FileName gives the full path of the file in case its posted from IE8.

> **Request.Files[0].FileName** gets value **C:\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Content\txt.jpg**

Whereas all the modern browsers including IE10 gives only the file name being uploaded without the path.

> **Request.Files[0].FileName** gets value **txt.jpg**

Not sure how this HttpPostedFileBase.FileName property is implemented by the Mvc Framework though.

Since MvcFileUploader uses this name along with StorageDirectory to save file which fails in case of IE8.

Fix:

In MvcUploaderTestController.UploadFile change this line

```
//overriding defaults
//x.FileName = Request.Files[i].FileName; //original
x.FileName = new FileInfo(Request.Files[i].FileName).Name;
```

This should save the file.

But for IE8 also tries to download json result returned from the action which results the progress always showing. Actually Blueimp plugin tries to upload file using iframe for IE8
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#content-type-negotiation

You need to send the response with content type text/plain based with accept header

Thanks